# why theme.xml directory in Android Studio hasn't any color primary

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, themes

[image]

hi, I'm new to Kotlin and xml languages. I'm using Android Studio Flamingo version. I have a problem.
my theme directory hasn't default values like colorPrimary,... and also ActionBar isn't available and I can just choose noActionBar.

I tried to add it manually but it's not the way it should be I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Android team promoting Jetpack Compose and dynamic color with Material 3. However if you want to use xml layout (legacy), you can generate theme using [Theme Builder](https://m3.material.io/theme-builder). Click export "Android Views (XML)" to export it to xml resources files.